# How to install Linux next to Android?

Tags: android, linux

How to install Linux (eg. Ubuntu) next to Android? So that was a possibility multii boot on start phone (Samsung Galaxy SII). Is it possible to create a chroot directly in Android?

Edit:

My question focused primarily on how to install Linux alongside android. I asked this question here because I wanted to learn about your experience, I read that not every mobile phone can do it. I do not understand why the topic is seen as off topic. Courtesy of Lance Preston some information I found here: http://whiteboard.ping.se/Android/Debian

Comment: It is off-topic because it has **nothing** to do with programming. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. There are other sites in the Stack Exchange network that would be better suited like [**Android Enthusiasts**](http://android.stackexchange.com/tour) or [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/tour). Although I personally am not sure where a question like this belongs. If you are unsure where to ask a question then I suggest you head over to [**Meta Stack Exchange**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) and ask where it would belong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you are searching for this: [How to run Debian or Ubuntu GNU/Linux on your Android](http://whiteboard.ping.se/Android/Debian)

Comment: How to make your own Linux distributions on Andorid?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the book [Embedded Android:Porting, Extending, and Customizing, By Karim Yaghmour](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do)

In the APPENDIX A Legacy User-Space, he talks about: "This appendix will show you
how to get a legacy Linux user-space to coexist side by side with the AOSP on top of the
same Linux kernel."